# How to develop Babel 6 plugins

Tags: babeljs

What process do you use to develop Babel 6 plugins?

Here's what I came up with to develop a plugin (`babel-plugin-test`):

1) In an empty folder run:

```
npm install babel-cli babel-preset-es2015
```

2) Create the file `src/test.js` (to test the plugin) with just:

```
class Person {
}
```

3) Create the folder `node_modules/babel-plugin-test` with the following contents

node_modules/babel-plugin-test/package.json

```
{
  "name": "babel-plugin-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-helper-plugin-test-runner": "^6.3.13"
  }
}
```

node_modules/babel-plugin-test/src/index.js

```
export default function ({types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      ClassDeclaration: function (node, parent) {
        console.log("XXX");
      }
    }
  };
}
```

4) Create a script that runs:

```
node_modules/babel-plugin-test/babel --presets es2015 --out-dir lib src
babel --plugins babel-plugin-test --presets es2015 --out-dir out src
```

So it compiles the plugin and then compiles `test.js` using the plugin and I see the console log and the output file (in this example I'm not changing anything).

There has to be a better way to do this. Maybe some way to use WebStorm or another Node debugger to put a breakpoint and play around (at least be able to inspect variables).

Answer (score 3):

The way to go is to run babel in code so you can get the transpiled code and compare against what you expect.

First transpile your plugin as you did, then in the test folder

```
var transformFileSync = require('babel-core').transformFileSync
var path = require('path')
var fs = require('fs')

var plugin = require('../lib/index').default
describe('My test', function (){
  it ('Transform', function(){
    var transformed = transformFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'testFilePath'), {
      plugins: [[plugin]]
    }).code
    var expectedCode = fs.readFileSync(..)
    assert.equal(transformed, expected)
  })
})
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/furstenheim/babel-plugin-meaningful-logs/blob/master/test/main.js). It is also possible to write the tests in ES6 importing modules, for that you need to provide mocha with a compiler, see [here](https://github.com/lodash/babel-plugin-lodash) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

For basic testing I use the wonderful [astexplorer](http://astexplorer.net/). Just set the parser to **babylon 6** and turn on **transform** and set it to **babelv6**. Then you can put your code in one pane, see the AST results in another, put your babel plugin in a third pane and see the plugin result in the fourth.

For a more complicated test I create two projects, one for the plugin and another one i want to test the plugin on. I **npm link** the two and configure the test project to use my plugin in babelrc. Then, whenever my plugin changes i just run babel on my file/project and see the results.

Im not sure if this is the best way but it works for me.